# Joining the numbers together from columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, join

I simplified the `data` to demonstrate what I want to do.
`data` looks like this:

```
data<-data.frame(date=c(20220823,20220801,20220904,20220906),
                 wk=c(4,1,2,2))
```

For example, `20220823` means August 23th, 2022.
`wk` means week.
What I want to do now is make a new column `date2` which represents the year,month, and week. So my expected output should be as follows:

```
data<-data.frame(date2=c(2022084,2022081,2022092,2022092))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)

 data |> 
  mutate(date2 = paste0(substr(date, 1,6), wk))
```

Output:

```
      date wk   date2
1 20220823  4 2022084
2 20220801  1 2022081
3 20220904  2 2022092
4 20220906  2 2022092
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
   mutate(date2 = str_replace(date, '..$', as.character(wk)))
      date wk   date2
1 20220823  4 2022084
2 20220801  1 2022081
3 20220904  2 2022092
4 20220906  2 2022092
```